# Where can I find details on installing and using Solr on Tomcat using the solr-common and solr-tomcat packages?

Tags: tomcat, apt, tomcat6, solr

I'm seeing lots of Solr/Tomcat installation instructions, but all of them install at least one of these packages from source.

Since there's tomcat6, solr-common, and solr-tomcat packages (in Ubuntu 10.4), I'd love to use them, but I can't find any kind of documentation on installing using them. I can't even tell what directory solr is stored in.

I get a "Welcome to Solr!" page at http://localhost:8080/solr/, but have no idea where the catalina home is, or where the solr configuration files are in this case. Can anyone point me to documentation?

Comment: There should be a README in /usr/share/doc/`packagename`/ Not sure if ubuntu just uses's debian's README.Debian or if they name it README.Ubuntu, but it will explain the Debian/Ubuntu specific things  you'll need to know about that package.

Comment: ahhh, that is the most useful info I've been able to find yet... perhaps post is as an actual answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just adding an official answer for DerfK who wrote a comment, thanks.  I would have marked your answer if you would have made your comment an official answer.

There is indeed a README file in `/usr/share/doc/solr-common/` that covers all the specific filename and usage for `solr-jetty` and `solr-tomcat` in Debian.